# How to make Magento supports new & used books, in a book store?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I want that each product (book), have two button "add new book to cart", "add used book to cart".

Do I need to develop something, or Magento do everything out-of-the-box?

If the answer is no, this what I have to do:

- Add two buttons, that add the same product, but different prices.
- Show in the list of product (category page), the two pricing.
- Manage the inventory of each variant.

Do I need to use `JavaScript`, `XML` Theme, or what?

I don't need step-by-step answer, just a general idea. how to achieve those goals.

I'm a `JavaScript` developer, so some code will help me to appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: @everyone: Do you have a link, for a book store (new & used) in Magento? OR pre-made theme?

Answer (score 0):

You could set each book as a configurable product with two variants based on a "new/used" attribute. Each variant would then have their own price and their own inventory.